# How to do a proper reboot, down to the BIOS, from the terminal?

Tags: 16.04, command-line, bios, reboot, systemd

Now that *systemd* took over the services management, the power controlling programs are a link to `systemctl`

```
chezmoi# ls -l /sbin | grep systemctl

lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 14 Jul 19 08:56 halt -> /bin/systemctl*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 14 Jul 19 08:56 poweroff -> /bin/systemctl*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 14 Jul 19 08:56 reboot -> /bin/systemctl*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 14 Jul 19 08:56 runlevel -> /bin/systemctl*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 14 Jul 19 08:56 shutdown -> /bin/systemctl*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 14 Jul 19 08:56 telinit -> /bin/systemctl*
```

The command `reboot` in particular will shutdown all services to restart them later on, but without going to a warm machine restart, like it used to do during the `init` era.

- is there a way to reboot down to the BIOS from the command line?

Could be also a setting I've set a long time ago that I forgot ...

*<sup>Using Ubuntu 16.04</sup>*

Edit:

- Doing a `reboot`, the desktop session ends, the [Ubuntu splash screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVXod.png) appears and runs for a few seconds, then 3 lines appear furtively: "kdump loaded", "kdump unloaded",  "Starting new kernel", then it's back to the login page.
- That happens while doing the `reboot` command, from a terminal, as `root`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reboot and go directly to UEFI/BIOS setup

```
sudo systemctl reboot --firmware-setup
```

This only works on systems running systemd init system (`cat /proc/1/comm`).

[Source](https://superuser.com/a/1083166/500826). [Documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemctl.html#reboot).

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

The option `-r` specifies reboot.
The option `now` can be replaced with a time in minutes; for example `+5`

Comment: Tried that, and `reboot`, see the edited question, and comments under @Rinzwind answer.

Answer (score 1):

That would be `reboot`.

A reboot shuts everything down and at the moment the system would turn itself off (when using a "halt" or "shutdown" instead of "reboot") it will start to boot up again.

The system will then show your systems logo (At that point you can press the key you need to press to enter your BIOS), grub, and eventually Ubuntu login and the desktop.

> but without going to a warm machine restart, like it used to do during the init era.

I do not understand this part (unless you changed th default settings(?)) A reboot with systemd is a "warm boot"; and it is similar to what was done during the init era.

Comment: Well, tried `reboot`, `shutdown -r now` and it doesn't go down to the BIOS.. Could be something specific to my setup :-(

Comment: @ringø -- can you elaborate more on what is not happening? what do you mean by down to bios?

Comment: Doing a `reboot`, the desktop session ends, the [Ubuntu splash screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVXod.png) appears and runs for a few seconds, then it's back to the login page.

Comment: That's  is "logout" you are describing. a "reboot" will go past the systems logo and past the bios. The splash comes after that. Unless you got a very quick SSD (then your eyes are too slow ;-) ).

Comment: That might look like a logout, but I'm doing a `reboot` command, from the terminal, as `root`.

Answer (score 1):

At the time (Ubuntu 16.04), it seems the only way to get a proper reboot down to the BIOS was

```
reboot -f
```

The `-f` makes a difference ; from the *man*

> **-f, --force**
>              Force immediate halt, power-off, or reboot. When specified once, this results in an immediate but clean shutdown by the system manager.
>              When specified twice, this results in an immediate shutdown without contacting the system manager. See the description of --force in
>              systemctl(1) for more details.